# Get all children categories of a collection of categories without using foreach in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-10

so I have this codes in my Category model. What it does is, you give it a single category collection and it will return all children category ids of that category in a one dimensional array of ids that can be used in a whereIn query.

```
private $descendants = [];

public function subcategories()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

public function children()
    {
        return $this->subcategories()->with('children');
    }

public function hasChildren(){
        if($this->children->count()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

public function findDescendants(Category $category){
        $this->descendants[] = $category->id;

        if($category->hasChildren()){
            foreach($category->children as $child){
                $this->findDescendants($child);
            }
        }
    }

public function getDescendants(Category $category){
        $this->findDescendants($category);
        return $this->descendants;
}
```

Usage:

```
$category = Category::where('id',$id)->first();
$children_ids = [];
$children_ids = $category->getDescendants($category);
```

It works. It is very useful in my filter. But when it comes to getting children ids of multiple categories, I had to use foreach loop and I had to call **getDescendants** multiple times thus creating multiple queries. What I want to accomplish are:

1. To improve performance how to do it in a single query without the need of using foreach loop? Where I want to feed it not just a single category but a collection of categories, and then it should return all children category ids of those categories.
2. How to return not just children ids but entire collection of children categories?

What usage I had in mind (please feel free to suggest a better approach)

Getting children ids from category collections:

```
$category = Category::where('parent_id',$id)->get();
$children_ids = [];
$children_ids = $category->getDescendants($category);
```

Getting children collection from category collections.

```
$category = Category::where('parent_id',$id)->get();
$children_ids = [];
$children_ids = $category->getDescendants($category);
```

Please help me accomplish this. Thank you.

Comment: I believe you can use a recursive approach with a custom database query. Define a method in your Category model to retrieve all descendants for a collection of categories and then use the method as follows to get both the children IDs and the entire collection of children categories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Hi Adie, how to do it? Can you give me some codes?

Comment: Hi Nice_Dev, no it does not answer my question. The link you provided is just the same with my current code, which is already working fine, recursively retrieving all the children ids.

Comment: what you have is a bad db design, you need to restructure your database, or at least add separate table to link category to  all child and subsequent childs directly to get their id and relation @0x9342812j1o

Comment: So define a method in your `Category` model say `getDescendantsForCategories ()` then you can get the children IDs by using `$categories->getDescendantsForCategories($categories)->pluck('id')->toArray();` or entire collection replaciing `pluck('id')->toArray();` with `get()`